# url formation settings language is georgian

Tags: php

here is url formation code, I want seo friendli urls but my language is georgian and my urls is georgian, i wont to convert georgian sumbols englis sumbols

function qa_q_request($questionid, $title)
/*
    Return the Q2A request for question $questionid, and make it search-engine friendly based on $title, which is
    shortened if necessary by removing shorter words which are generally less meaningful.
*/
    {
        if (qa_to_override(**FUNCTION**)) { $args=func_get_args(); return qa_call_override(**FUNCTION**, $args); }

```
    require_once QA_INCLUDE_DIR.'king-app-options.php';
    require_once QA_INCLUDE_DIR.'king-util-string.php';

    $title=qa_block_words_replace($title, qa_get_block_words_preg());

    $words=qa_string_to_words($title, true, false, false);

    $wordlength=array();
    foreach ($words as $index => $word)
        $wordlength[$index]=qa_strlen($word);

    $remaining=qa_opt('q_urls_title_length');

    if (array_sum($wordlength)>$remaining) {
        arsort($wordlength, SORT_NUMERIC); // sort with longest words first

        foreach ($wordlength as $index => $length) {
            if ($remaining>0)
                $remaining-=$length;
            else
                unset($words[$index]);
        }
    }

    $title=implode('-', $words);
    if (qa_opt('q_urls_remove_accents'))
        $title=qa_string_remove_accents($title);

    return (int)$questionid.'/'.$title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL-friendly version of a page title is called a slug.  Here is a script to convert a string to a slug.

https://code.google.com/p/php-slugs/

If you are using a CMS then it is likely to have such a function inbuilt that you can use.